# Token is null causing invalid ModelState

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, token

I have a model to allow a user to reset a password:

```
public class PasswordResetViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Please ensure requestor email is valid")]
    [UIHint("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password), Compare("Password")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Token { get; set; }
}
```

The token is set through the following action method:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PasswordResetEmail(UserEmailViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                AppUser user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    // Don't reveal that the user does not exist or is not confirmed
                    TempData["message"] = null;
                    return View("Login"); 
                }

                var token = userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user).Result;
                var resetLink = Url.Action("PasswordReset", "Account", new { token = token }, protocol: HttpContext.Request.Scheme);
                var message = "<a href=\"" + resetLink + "\">Click here to reset your password</a>";
                string subjectLine = "Reset your password";
                //send email with email service
                emailService.SendHtmlEmail(message, user.Email, subjectLine);

                TempData["message"] = $"Check email for password reset link";
                return View("Login");
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View("ForgotPassword");
        }
```

The email redirects to the following View:

```
@model PasswordResetViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Reset Password";
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<div class="bg-primary panel-body"><h4>ViewBag.Title</h4></div>
<div class="text-danger" asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="PasswordReset" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Token" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Email"></label>
        <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Password"></label>
        <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ConfirmPassword"></label>
        <input asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-space" type="submit">Reset Password</button>
</form>
```

However, upon submission the token is blank in the following action item, leading to an invalid ModelState

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PasswordReset(PasswordResetViewModel obj)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                AppUser user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(obj.Email);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    IdentityResult result = await userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, obj.Token, obj.Password);

                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        TempData["message"] = $"Password reset successful!";
                        return View("Login");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AddErrorsFromResult(result);
                        TempData["message"] = $"Error while resetting the password. Password was not reset. Send another reset password and try again";
                        return View("ForgotPassword");
                    }
                }
            else //user email not found in database
            {
                TempData["message"] = $"Error while resetting the password. Password was not reset. Send another reset password and try again";
                return View("ForgotPassword");
            }
        }
```

The email link works and appears to have a valid token. However, this token value is not passed from the View to the controller in the `PasswordReset` action method.

Below is the rendered HTML

```
<div class="bg-primary panel-body"><h4>ViewBag.Title</h4></div>
<div class="text-danger validation-summary-valid" data-valmsg-summary="true"><ul><li style="display:none"></li>
</ul></div>
<form method="post" action="/Account/PasswordReset">
    <input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Token field is required." id="Token" name="Token" value="" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Email">Email</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="email" data-val="true" data-val-email="Please ensure requestor email is valid" data-val-required="The Email field is required." id="Email" name="Email" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Password">Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Password field is required." id="Password" name="Password" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ConfirmPassword">ConfirmPassword</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" data-val="true" data-val-equalto="&#x27;ConfirmPassword&#x27; and &#x27;Password&#x27; do not match." data-val-equalto-other="*.Password" data-val-required="The ConfirmPassword field is required." id="ConfirmPassword" name="ConfirmPassword" />
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-space" type="submit">Reset Password</button>
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8P701H9_W2VHikt7vFU7qE_hDXNPQe-vU2zRITMm_SakSlqmLU7lTfycwmVg4bPhvqWHdv7d3n4YbJYOMqCVK55Rn0KqQCoZplL9a_eZDF48oiQExiaSTn4BcXdfhzWqjc1oQgyUQTyCbt1Zu1zhrva5dWPXXhXtxF442_Zn11GL8zBiqEsscAt2VbpcmkjJ8g" /></form>
```

I tried changing the line to

```
var resetLink = Url.Action("PasswordReset", "Account", new { Token = token }, protocol: HttpContext.Request.Scheme);
```

in the event that the `Token` parameter was case sensitive but it didn't fix it.

Comment: How does the token actually get to the view? Does it appear in View Source?

Comment: Please add the rendered HTML to your question too.

Comment: @RAM see the edit. The Token value is null, but __RequestVerificationToken has the correct value. I've used a similar approach before without this issue

Comment: @SLaks I'm new to .NET Core, but I thought it was passed via the asp-for="Token"

Comment: But what does `Token` there come from? How is that view rendered?

Comment: Btw. why are you calling `GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync` synchronously inside an async method? You can just await it.

Comment: Token is blank because you haven't assigned any value to it: `<input type="hidden" asp-for="Token" value="ADD VALUE HERE" />`

Comment: @FCin I caught the async issue after I posted. After I changed it, the issue remained

Comment: @SLaks the Token is set in the linked url XXXX/Account/PasswordReset?token=TOKEN_GENERATED_VAL

Comment: But how does that get to the view?

Comment: @coolhand, you should fill the Token property of the ViewModel from the token argument of a Get Action method named PasswordReset. Then pass the ViewModel to the view. I show it in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48587760/token-is-null-causing-invalid-modelstate/48588203#48587760).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a `Get` `Action` method with `token` argument! Like the following code and fill the `Token` property of the `ViewModel` in the `Get` method and pass it to the `View` else it will be empty:

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> PasswordReset(string token)
{
        //Other codes

    var vm = new PasswordResetViewModel();
    vm.Token = token;


    return View("ForgotPassword", vm);
}
```

Now call the `ResetPassword` link manually (eq: `http://localhost:PORT/Account/ResetPassword?token=123456`) and see the rendered HTML. The hidden input of the `Token` field should has this value: `123456`

Comment: Thank you. I was incorrectly using `public ViewResult PasswordReset() => View()` without passing the string token